# ZIP confused. Plugin appears to be corrupted

Tags: firefox-addon, zip

I'm trying to write my first Firefox extension (I use Firefox 8.0.1) and I'm stuck:
I have a working sample from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/package/ - downloaded file plugin.zip renamed to plugin.xpi seems to be OK. Then I extract it to folder, and without any modification compress it again (using default Ubuntu 10.04LTS context menu package archiver). When I'm trying to install recompressed_plugin.xpi Firefox returns:
"This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt.". What am I doing wrong?

Which compression tools should I use to get it working? How can I determine the internal ZIP type (both files plugin.zip and recompressed_plugin.zip have the same MIME type: Zip archive (application/zip))?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't compress the package correctly - this message means that there is no `install.rdf` at the top level of your ZIP file. You've probably run `zip recompressed_plugin.xpi plugin/` instead of `zip recompressed_plugin.xpi plugin/*`. To test run `unzip -l recompressed_plugin.xpi`, it should list `install.rdf` and not `plugin/install.rdf` or something like that.

Comment: That was helpful. On my system, the only way to remove the leading directory was to cd into the plugin directory and zip from whithin it: "cd plugin/; zip -r ../recompressed_plugin.xpi ./*"